# How would I use a regex to add a number to every second value?

Tags: regex

I have a [text file](http://pastebin.com/SqiBu5n9).

As you can see, in every position field, there are 10 values.

I would like to add x to every OTHER value starting with the first in each position field, how would I use regex to achieve this?

For example:

```
#Vestisland
1=
{
    position=
    {
63.500 1892.500 104.000 1882.000 82.500 1896.500 8.000 1833.000 61.000 1893.500         }
    rotation=
    {
0.087 0.000 0.000 0.000 1.571       }
    height=
    {
0.000 0.000 0.000 20.000 0.000      }
}
```

I would like to add x to the following bolded values.

**63.500** 1892.500 **104.000** 1882.000 **82.500** 1896.500 **8.000** 1833.000 **61.000** 1893.500

Comment: In which environment / language?

Comment: It doesn't have to be any in particular just one that can make a simple script to achieve what I need.

Comment: You have to specify regex flavor otherwise a general working solution may take much more than necessary steps to achieve desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP, there is a handy function called preg_replace_callback which gets all the matches one by one, and you return all the changes you want. Here is the code for it:

```
    <?
$text = '#Vestisland
    1=
    {
        position=
        {
63.500 1892.500 104.000 1882.000 82.500 1896.500 8.000 1833.000 61.000 1893.500         }
        rotation=
        {
0.087 0.000 0.000 0.000 1.571       }
        height=
        {
0.000 0.000 0.000 20.000 0.000      }
    }
#Austisland
    2=
    {
        position=
        {
225.000 1897.000 211.000 1910.000 232.000 1918.000 147.000 1819.000 229.000 1891.000        }
        rotation=
        {
0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 -0.611      }
        height=
        {
0.000 0.000 0.000 20.000 0.000      }
    }';
$x = 100;
$fun = function($t) use ($x) {
    $t = $t[0];
    $t = explode(' ', $t);
    $t[0] = number_format($t[0] + $x, 3);
    return implode(' ', $t);
};
$outerFun = function($t) use ($x, $fun) {
    $text = $t[0];
    $newText = preg_replace_callback('/[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+ [0-9]+\\.[0-9]+/', $fun, $text);
    return $newText;
};

$allNewText = preg_replace_callback('/position.*?rotation/s', $outerFun, $text);
echo $allNewText;
```

Comment: Excellent, the only issue is that this code adds 100 to every value when I only need it to add to every other value in the position field starting with the first, like I have in bold in the original question. Any way around that?

Comment: That's strange. I tested the code here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/33fb4e8da7bb0392193840eccb005b1b33d96c79 and it is applying it to only every other value. If you only want it to be applied to the position fields you would have to split up the string, apply the code to the first part and join the parts together again.

Comment: Ah you're right I was looking at the wrong values! Thank you. Is there another way to make it just the position fields other than splitting up the string as I have 1000+ more and I can't really split up every string?

Comment: I edited the code. Now it has an outer function wich gets the callback from an outer regex splitting between position and rotation where your numbers are.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Exactly what I needed.